# How do I return multiple strings from a method in C#

Tags: c#, methods

If I have something like:

```
        static string characterName()
    {
        Console.Write("Name your character: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Is this correct? (Y/N): ");
        string nameConfirm = Console.ReadLine();
        return nameConfirm;
    }
```

How can I change this so it outputs both nameConfirm and name.
The nameConfirm goes into:

```
        static string stageOne(string nameConfirm)
    {
        while (nameConfirm != "Y")
            nameConfirm = Program.characterName();
        if (nameConfirm == "Y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Alright, lets continue.");
            nameConfirm = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return nameConfirm;
```

That works fine but I want to be able to call upon the name later if its needed.

Comment: one way is to make the return collection of `string` rather than `string`, like `string[]` or `List<string>` or `IEnumerable<string>` or `Dictionary<string, string>` and so on... You could also return `Tuple<string, string>`

Comment: you can return a string collection, or an object with multiple string properties, or a tuple, or use the `out` keyword and functionality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you could do this that aren't too overkill, the first is to return a string array

```
static string[] characterName()
{
    Console.Write("Name your character: ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Is this correct? (Y/N): ");
    string nameConfirm = Console.ReadLine();
    return new string[]{ nameConfirm, name };
}
```

This object can then be used like so

```
string[] names = characterName();
string runStageOne = stageOne(names[0]);
```

The other way you can do this is to return the `nameConfirm` variable and use the `name` variable as a ref, so your method would change to

```
static string characterName(ref string name)
{
    Console.Write("Name your character: ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Is this correct? (Y/N): ");
    string nameConfirm = Console.ReadLine();
    return nameConfirm;
}
```

And would be called like

```
string name = "";
string nameConfirmed = characterName(ref name);
```

By using the ref keyword on your input parameter, it means that when the value of name is changed in the method, that change is reflected outside of it too

Comment: I hardly ever use arrays after the introduction of `List<T>`

Answer (score 0):

You could return a List, a string[], or define a class to represent the result of the method (ie with two string properties)...